# google maps v3 API mouseover with GeoJson polygon layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mouseover, geojson

How to get the mouseover event to work with google maps Api V3 on Polygon shapes ?

I cannot get the event to fire on mouseover.

```
  var data_layer25 = new google.maps.Data({ map: map });
                                data_layer25.loadGeoJson('http://example.com/Assets/GeoJson/USA-MO.GeoJson');
                                data_layer25.setStyle({
                                            fillColor: '    #808000  ',
                                            strokeWeight: 1
                                    });
                                google.maps.event.addListener((data_layer25), "click", function () { window.location = "/RepTerritory/index/9" });
                    google.maps.event.addListener((data_layer25), "mouseover", function () {
                          this.setOptions({ fillColor: "#00FF00" });
                     });

                    google.maps.event.addListener((data_layer25), "mouseout", function () {
                          this.setOptions({ fillColor: "#FF0000" });
            });
            data_layer25.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this to change the style of `Data Layer`s on mouse events:

```
data_layer25.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
     data_layer25.setStyle({
         fillColor: "#00FF00"
     });
});

data_layer25.addListener('mouseout', function(e) {
     data_layer25.setStyle({
         fillColor: "#FF0000"
     });
});
```

Comment: You should probably create a new question for that because that's a whole new problem. You are probably creating multiple instances of `infowindow` instead of reusing one.

Comment: Moving the data layer worked, thank you for the help.